# Transaction has 900+ confirmations but doesn't show up in my wallet

Tags: lost-transactions, exodus

I've received a payment to [1KGUphZbuMj5dU9WD4ZKVqHdtz2jSLPXv3](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/1KGUphZbuMj5dU9WD4ZKVqHdtz2jSLPXv3). It has over 900 confirmations, but it doesn't show up in my Exodus v20.12.22 wallet on Windows, yet. I have no idea what to do. Is there a way that I can get my wallet to recognize the transaction?

Comment: What services and wallet were you using ?

Comment: Wallet is exodus.

Comment: Without more information it is difficult to provide help. ie: which wallet software are you using? software version? have you used this software successfully in the past, or is it a new install? does your wallet show the receiving address? is it properly synced to the network? what OS are you using? etc.

Comment: Exodus / 20.12.22 / Have used in the past and successful / yes it shows / no idea / windows 10

Answer (score 3):

> 900+ confirms ...

Then you have definitely, incontrovertibly and irreversibly already received the money even though your wallet doesn't know yet.

> ... but nothing in wallet

Sure but remember that wallets don't *contain* money. They check the public blockchain to add up how much money you have.

> No idea what to do.
>
> > is it properly synced to the network?
> >
> > > no idea

https://support.exodus.io/article/75-how-do-i-refresh-my-wallet

says

> Did you send a coin to your wallet, but it's not showing in your balance? Is your Bitcoin displaying incorrectly? Do you get an error when trying to send?
>
> If so, then your wallet may be out of sync with the blockchain. A quick wallet refresh tends to fix a number of balance-related problems and help your wallet correctly align with the network.
>
> As a first step, make sure you are using the latest release of Exodus. Here's how to [upgrade](https://support.exodus.io/article/27-how-do-i-upgrade-exodus).
>
> Refresh the wallet by clicking the logo:
>
> 1. Open the crypto wallet you want to refresh inside of Exodus.
> 2. Mouse over the asset's logo and click.
> 3. A dialogue asks you if you want to rescan the blockchain. Click Rescan. When the refresh icon is finished spinning, all your transactions will be updated and refreshed.

I think I'd try refreshing before upgrading but it's your call.

I hope you have your recovery phrase or your private key written down somewhere safe.